# Edge URL vs subdomain

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean-spaces

In Digital Ocean Spaces (S3) there are 3 URLs for static assets that I've uploaded.

`Origin` and `Edge` (they're the same) and a subdomain that I've configured. I couldn't find if there is a difference in performance in loading these assets on external websites (where they're placed) when using the `Edge` or subdomain URL. Should I be using one or the other for linking to my static assets?

**Example**

Edge: `https://my-cdn.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/example/asset.js`

Subdomain: `https://cdn.my-website.com/example/asset.js`